# Ransack: Show the attribute of a has_many relationship sorted by Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I have a `Commodity(name:string)` model and a `Price(amount:float)` model such that:

```
class Commodity < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :prices
end
```

And

```
class Price < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commodity
end
```

Thus, one commodity can have many prices.

I have a Ransack search form for Commodity, which obviously enables a user to search for commodities. I wish to include a `sort_link(@q, :prices_amount)` sorting filter. Clicking this link should display all the commodities sorted according to their prices (if one commodity has multiple prices, that commodity will show multiple times, with each repeated commodity's price shown accordingly). Currently, Ransack does indeed show a commodity multiple times, (as many as the number of prices each commodity has) but I do not know a way to display that price for each repeated commodity.

**I wish to know how should I display that price in my frontend**. I display the query results via:

```
<%=@commodities.each do |commodity|%>
  <%=commodity.name%>    
  <%=commodity.prices.first.amount%> <!-- In place of prices.first, I was to display the amount that Ransack found -->
<%end%>
```

I'm using `prices.first.amount` right now as a placeholder. How do I replace this by the `amount` that Ransack found while sorting?

Comment: can you give more information? you have a commodity table that shows all the commodities, right? but you want to sort by prices, but if it has many prices, how do you want to do it? the sort link with use the lower price that the commodity has, or the bigger? give more details please

Comment: Hi @xploshioOn, I have edited my question. If it's still not clear as to what I want, I'll edit it again.

Comment: Ok it gives more details, can you add too the code that you have at the moment to show all the commodities?

Comment: @xploshioOn, I've added code to display commodities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend creating a scope to include the price with the `Commodity` instance. e.g.

```
class Commodity < ApplicationRecord
  scope :with_price, -> {joins(:prices).select("commodities.*, prices.amount as price_amount")}
end
```

This will create a virtual attribute `price_amount` on your instances of `Commodity`

In the controller it would be something like

```
@q = Commodity.ransack(params[:q])
@commodities = @q.result.with_price
```

Assuming that you're "Displaying" these as a table you can display the results as requested using the following

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= sort_link(@q, :name, 'Commodity' %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link(@q, :prices_amount, 'Price') %></th>
    </tr> 
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @commodities.each do |commodity| %>
      <tr> 
        <td><%= commodity.name %></td>
        <td><%= number_to_currency(commodity.price_amount) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect! This is brilliant, simple, and exactly what I  was looking for. This should probably be explained on the Ransack documentation too.

Comment: @a3y3 this actually has nothing to do with `ransack` as you mentioned your sorting was working correctly the issue was you were not sure which price was causing the position. When you run a select query in `ActiveRecord` it will map all the columns into `attributes` for your active record instance so we just added `prices.amount` to those attributes under the alias `price_amount` so that you knew which price caused the position in the sort. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is some missing information to this to be clear, but yes, it's simple. and you even have the answer, if you have the association like in the example you posted, then it have to work with the code you sent

```
sort_link(@q, :prices_amount)
```

where "prices" is the name of the association and "amount" is your attribute.